# Application Insights Data Limited Importing Into PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, azure-application-insights, m

I'm attempting to import data from Azure Application Insights into PowerBI. The issue is that, regardless of the `timespan` I set, I seem to only be pulling about a week's worth of data. Here's what the M query looks like:

```
let AnalyticsQuery =
let Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<uuid>/query", 
[Query=[#"query"="customEvents
| project customDimensions
",#"x-ms-app"="AAPBI",#"timespan"="P30D"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,60,0)])),
TypeMap = #table(
{ "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
{ 
{ "string",   Text.Type },
{ "int",      Int32.Type },
{ "long",     Int64.Type },
{ "real",     Double.Type },
{ "timespan", Duration.Type },
{ "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
{ "bool",     Logical.Type },
{ "guid",     Text.Type },
{ "dynamic",  Text.Type }
}),
DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),
ColumnsWithType = Table.Join(Columns, {"type"}, TypeMap , {"AnalyticsTypes"}),
Rows = Table.FromRows(DataTable[rows], Columns[name]), 
Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(ColumnsWithType, (c) => { c{0}, c{3}}))
in
Table
in
    AnalyticsQuery
```

I was thinking this was a size issue, but I've already narrowed it down to a single column (albeit a wide one) and it's still not returning any more data.

Narrowing the returned dataset to two columns has increased the dataset to include a few weeks instead of less than a week, but I'm still looking for a bigger dataset. Here's the latest query:

```
let AnalyticsQuery =
let Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<uuid>/query", 
[Query=[#"query"="customEvents
| extend d=parse_json(customDimensions)
| project timestamp, d[""Properties""]
| order by timestamp desc
| where timestamp <= now() and d_Properties <> """"
",#"x-ms-app"="AAPBI"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,4,0)])),
TypeMap = #table(
{ "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
{ 
{ "string",   Text.Type },
{ "int",      Int32.Type },
{ "long",     Int64.Type },
{ "real",     Double.Type },
{ "timespan", Duration.Type },
{ "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
{ "bool",     Logical.Type },
{ "guid",     Text.Type },
{ "dynamic",  Text.Type }
}),
DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),
ColumnsWithType = Table.Join(Columns, {"type"}, TypeMap , {"AnalyticsTypes"}),
Rows = Table.FromRows(DataTable[rows], Columns[name]), 
Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(ColumnsWithType, (c) => { c{0}, c{3}}))
in
Table,
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(AnalyticsQuery,{{"timestamp", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: Are you sure that your data is not complete? Because normally in Power BI (in the preview and the query editor) you just see a few rows (~1000).

Comment: Yes, I threw a visualization on the report with a data grid, and the earliest timestamp is around 7/30. There's data going back much further.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into either table buffering or directquery: [see this discussion](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-Improve-Query-Reference-performance-for-large-tables/m-p/23901/highlight/true#M7607)

Comment: I don't believe this is a matter of volume on the PowerBI side, it appears to be a limiter from Application Insights.

Comment: I have used Json data as source, and Power BI gave me intermittent problems with loading the data (some parts of the data were not loading). Using table buffering gave me all the data after all (it did make it slower, but that was not a problem)